# amazon rds django recreate database

Tags: database, django, amazon-web-services, rds

i've made some changes in the model.py and i would like to have them reflected to the db.

As far as i understood, `syncdb` actually does not recreate the db but only updates it.

since i modified a field from `integer` to `biginteger` the syncdb doesn't change the database structure.

how can i have my database updated?

locally i remove the sqllite file and it's recreated.
now, i don't know what to do since i can't remove the db. Yet, i can delete the db but by doing this the EB machine stop working.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's a tool for this called `south`. http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/about.html